# Debug into nightly build of ASP.NET MVC4 using Symbolserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, debug-symbols

I used this description to get the nightly build of ASP.NET MVC for my project

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/06/01/using-nightly-asp-net-web-stack-nuget-packages-with-vs-2012-rc.aspx

Its pulls the assemblies sucesfully from  nuget and I can run the project.

I now try to debug into the pdb pulled from the MS symbol server. Thats actually the point: I dont know if these symbols are realy located on the servers. Either I am doing something wrong or symbols are not available.

Here are my debug settings:

[image]

These are my symbol servers
[image]

This is what I see when I try to step into a method located in System.Web.Mvc.dll
[image]

These are the modules loaded:

[image]

I downloaded the nightly build on the third of september. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced exactly the same issue. You need to use the Symbols hosted on MyGet. Please see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/30/getting-symbols-and-source-with-asp-net-nightly-nuget-packages.aspx